# Angular 4 HTTP custom headers

Tags: http, cors, http-headers

In service:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers = headers.append('sessionToken', token);
```

in request:

```
{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":[{"name":"sessionToken","value":"22ddc387-dfab-4e03-bbf9-241d75968133","op":"a"}],"headers":{},"lazyInit":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}}}
```

server response:

```
There are no «sessiontoken» in CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Headers»
```

Why doesn't it add "sessiontoken" into headers?

Answer (score 1):

Because as said in the error,

> There are no «sessiontoken» in CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Headers»

Your server must return a response with the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "sessionToken"
```

Comment: but parameter added into 'lazyUpdate'? headers are empty

Comment: No, in your server configuration, the same way you added your CORS headers.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: No I can't. This isn't an Angular issue, that's a server issue. First of all, you should state what back-end you're using, then rephrase your question to ask how to add CORs headers to your server.